# Shadowing (redefining) symbol in commmon-lisp package ends up with errors

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp, shadowing, redefine

I found out that my package has a problem shadowing `delete` from the `common-lisp package`. I have tried various types of `shadowing`, but none of them worked for me. I guess I'm using it wrong, but still can't make it to work.

> I have shortened the code just to show the problem part

This solution throws **error**: Redefining macro DELETE visible from package COMMON-LISP.

```
 (in-package "CL-USER")

 (defpackage :simple-db
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:shadow :delete)
  (:export :delete))
```

Another solution throws **error**: Duplicated symbols in "SIMPLE-DB" defpackage: "DELETE".

```
 (in-package "CL-USER")

 (defpackage :simple-db
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:shadow :delete)
  (:export :delete)
  (:shadowing-import-from :simple-db :delete))
```

Comment: Which code throws the error for the first case?

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having is probably not in your package definition (the first one is fine), it's in packages which want to use your package, and *also* to use `CL`.  Those packages end up with references both to `CL:DELETE` *and* `SIMPLE-DB:DELETE`.  Given your definition:

```
(defpackage :simple-db
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:shadow :delete)
  (:export :delete))
```

Then any package which wants to use *both* `SIMPLE-DB` *and* `CL` will get an error.

```
(defpackage :simple-db-user
  ;; this is an error
  (:use :common-lisp :simple-db))
```

You will also see this in any package (for instance `CL-USER`) if you simply say `(use-package :simple-db)`.

The traditional way to resolve this error is use `SHADOWING-IMPORT` to pick the symbol you want:

```
(defpackage :simple-db-user
  (:use :common-lisp :simple-db)
  (:shadowing-import-from :simple-db :delete))
```

or, in an existing package:

```
(shadowing-import '(:delete) :simple-db)
```

There are (I think) nicer solutions which involve defining packages which are 'like' `CL` but which redefine some symbols, and which you then treat like a mutant `CL` package, but those solutions require macrology to make them easy to use which I won't give here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem:

```
* (cl:defpackage :simple-db
    (:use :common-lisp)
    (:shadow :delete)
    (:export :delete))

#<PACKAGE "SIMPLE-DB">
* (defun simple-db:delete (foo) foo)

SIMPLE-DB:DELETE

* (describe 'simple-db:delete)

SIMPLE-DB:DELETE
  [symbol]

DELETE names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (FOO)
  Derived type: (FUNCTION (T) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
  Source form:
    (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA SIMPLE-DB:DELETE
        (FOO)
      (BLOCK SIMPLE-DB:DELETE FOO))
```

Comment: I made it to work by using (cl:defpackage ...) but it just moved this problem to defsystem

Comment: @dyouteotyi: you need to show a complete reproduceable case.